# Contact Form 7 Selection Field Values in Mail

Tags: php, jquery, html, wordpress, contact-form-7

I'm using WordPress and Contact Form 7 to allow users to submit their details.
Now, I wanted to make a `select` dropdown menu with `option` fields.
HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 af-outer af-required form-group af-inner hfix">
              <select class="form-control" id="selfix">
                    <option disabled selected>How did you hear about us?</option>
                    <option value="From a colleague">- From a colleague</option>
                    <option value="From my partner">- From my friend</option>
                    <option value="Other, please specify">- Other, please specify</option>
              </select>
        <textarea id="otherinp" rows="1" style="display: none;"></textarea>
        </div>
```

This si clear, I believe. The `textarea` with the id `otherinp` shows only is "*Other, please specify*" is selected with this jquery solution:

```
$('#selfix').change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == "Other, please specify") {
        $('#otherinp').css('display', 'block');
     }
});
```

Ok, but the issue appears when I want to collect the details. In Contact Form 7, you use shortcodes, like `[select-form]` to get these details. However, I do not have shortcodes as I was using plain HTML, while doing this.

Is there any way I can collect the upper HTML or convert it to shortcode somehow?

Example, of shortcodes for other fields:

```
Form Details:

Full Name: [text-471]
Email: [email-326]
Phone: [phone-007]
```

Comment: Why don't you give id to select box and keep same jQuery code, refer [http://contactform7.com/checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-menus](http://contactform7.com/checkboxes-radio-buttons-and-menus/)

Comment: Because I have a custom css styles... I couldn't make it better. Please post code.

Comment: `[select id:selfix "How did you hear about us?" "- From a colleague" "- Other, please specify"]`